# What if the result of reduceByKey(_+_) exceed int range

Tags: scala, apache-spark, mapreduce, reduce, integer-overflow

I am trying to do a simple MR job in Spark, here is the codes:

```
val testRDD = someRDD.map((_, 1)).reduceByKey(_+_)
```

In the map stage, the value is Int, what if in the reduce stage, the value is too large that exceed the Int range? I can probably do like this

```
val testRDD = someRDD.map((_, 1.toLong)).reduceByKey(_+_)
```

But is there any better idea?

Answer (score 2):

Nothing Spark specific. It will simply result in an [integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow):

```scala
sc.parallelize(Seq(("a", Integer.MAX_VALUE), ("a", 1))).reduceByKey(_ + _).first

// (String, Int) = (a,-2147483648)
```

If you suspect that overflow errors may occur you should definitely use more appropriate data type and `Long` is a good choice for integral values:

```scala
sc.parallelize(Seq(
  ("a", Integer.MAX_VALUE.toLong), ("a", 1L)
)).reduceByKey(_ + _).first

// (String, Long) = (a,2147483648)
```